# Console Logging a setInterval counter outputs every number up till the current one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, counter, setinterval

I am making a counter to update a progress bar as time goes on.

I decided to use a setInterval function to update the counter every second, which would then update the progress bar, but the bar was showing weird behaviour as it would jump up and down a lot.

I went to console log to see what values the counter was taking as the setInterval was updating them, and every second, random numbers from 0 to the current value of counter was being outputted, and I have no idea why.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

```js
let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  counter++;
  console.log(counter)
}, 1000);
```

Below is what some of the output looked like:

9
13
8
11
9
12
15
7
9
17
9
11

I tried taking the counter addition and making it its own function and then calling it from within the setInterval, but that also did not work.

Comment: This question needs more context. Since you've tagged this with [tag:reactjs], I imagine the problem is creating new intervals on each render but that's just a guess

Comment: I put that code snippet into a web page and opened it in a browser. It logged numbers to the console, each one 1 greater than the previous one, just like you’d expect.

Comment: Hi Allison, I have run the code snippet in the question and it worked for me. If you are using React.Js, you can use a UseEffect to resolve the issue Phil mentioned. Check out this article for more information https://upmostly.com/tutorials/setinterval-in-react-components-using-hooks

Comment: Please ensure you've include a [mre]. The current code works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have noticed, your `setInterval()` example will output correctly in vanilla JS (you can even check in the browser's developer console). But since you mentioned a progress bar and this is tagged with `reactjs`, I am assuming you have this function inside of a React component. If so, the random output is likely reflective of the component lifecycle, i.e. being created, mounted, etc.

Assuming this is in a React component, you might try using a state variable and use lifecycle hooks, for example:

```
const MyProgressBar = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  // Run on mount
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      console.log(counter);
      setCounter(counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    // Cleanup when unmounted
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

// Rest of component
}
```